# Preserving parcel labels when importing WFS data with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, wfs, ogr2ogr

I'm currently working on a project where I need to import geographic data from a WFS server using GDAL (ogr2ogr) into a GeoPackage format. My objective is to preserve the data exactly as it is, especially the parcel labels contained in a specific field (cp:CadastralParcel.label). These labels follow a "Number/Number" pattern (e.g., "193/2") and are crucial for parcel identification.

However, during the import process, I've noticed that GDAL attempts to automatically convert these field values into integers, leading to the loss of critical information – for example, "193/2" simply becomes "193".

I've tried several approaches to solve this issue, including using the -mapFieldType option in ogr2ogr to explicitly define field types, but to no avail. The data must be retained in its original format without any automatic type conversions being applied.

Does anyone have experience with similar challenges or know of a method to prevent GDAL from performing these automatic conversions? Are there specific options or workarounds I could employ to maintain data integrity?

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time

proj_lib_path = 'C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.28.9/share/proj'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = proj_lib_path

start_index = 0
while start_index < 5000000:
    command = [
        'ogr2ogr',
        '-f', 'GPKG',
        f'C:/Users/tmohr/Programmieren/Hessen/output/output_{start_index}.gpkg',
        '-mapFieldType', 'Integer64=String',
        f'WFS:https://inspire-hessen.de/ows/services/org.2.dd63cf0f-cf8a-4a69-be4c-b5c056b8528b_wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cp:CadastralParcel&count=10000&startIndex={start_index}'
    ]
    result = subprocess.run(command, text=True, capture_output=True, env=os.environ)
    print("stdout:", result.stdout)
    print("stderr:", result.stderr)
    start_index += 10000
```

The Erro I'll get:

```
Warning 1: Value '1/3' of field cp:CadastralParcel.label parsed incompletely to integer 1.
Warning 1: Value '5/2' of field cp:CadastralParcel.label parsed incompletely to integer 5.
Warning 1: Value '19/1' of field cp:CadastralParcel.label parsed incompletely to integer 19.
```

The interesting thing is that the error appears randomly and not for every request.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but if the cause if this issue can't be identified, it may be worth creating the (empty) output dataset manually, where you can make sure that the field is a String value.  Then use the `-append` option with `ogr2ogr` to write the output to the existing dataset.

Comment: Possibly you need to specify a data type used by GeoPackage, so not `string` but `text` ~ http://www.geopackage.org/spec/#table_column_data_types